# java- trying to use/convert interface for use with/in place of an abstract class

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I want to use a java library that acts as a substitute for ArrayLists...This library ("Vanilla Java Collections")requires an interface to be declared in the following manner--

```
interface MutableBoolean {
    public void setFlag(boolean b);
    public boolean getFlag();
}
```

This is how this list is declared--

```
// create a huge array of MutableBoolean
HugeArrayList<MutableBoolean> hugeList = new HugeArrayBuilder<MutableBoolean>() {}.create();
List<MutableBoolean> list = hugeList;
```

This is how data is retrieved--

```
for (MutableTypes mb : list) {
boolean b1 = mb.getBoolean();
```

There can be multiple data types within the same interface to insert/retrieve string, integer, double etc values...

Now, in an application I am working on there is a custom variable definition--

```
public abstract class Variable implements MutableVariable  {

    abstract public byte[] toBinary();
    abstract public byte[] toBinary(String charset);
    abstract public String toString();
    abstract public String toString(String charset);
    abstract public List toList();
    abstract public boolean isEmpty();
    abstract public Object getWrappedObject();
    ----plus some more functions----
```

Also there is a class "NodeVariable" which extends "Variable" and another class "ListVariable" which implements Variable-- Each ListVariable has a List plus some utility functions pertaining to lists and string manipulation.

I want to implement the array substitute("Vanilla Java Collections") - which requires an interface- in place of the 'ListVariable'. But the class "Variable" is an abstract class. So I am confused here- how do I implement the interface so that I can use the ArrayList Substitute("Vanilla Java Collections") in place of "ListVariable"?

And is this possible with minimal changes to the existing code that utilises "ListVariable" i.e. by making all/most changes to the "ListVariable" class?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want ot use a class named `ArayListVariable` that you can use anywhere where you could use a `ListVariable`.  If this is the case, you can either extend the `Variable` abstract class

```
public class ArrayListVariable extends Variable
{
  // overrides of required functions
}
```

or implement the `MutableVariable` interface

```
public class ArrayListVariable implements MutableVariable
{
  // implementations of required functions
}
```